# Word choice - Way of / to / for

Tags: word-usage

What I mean is getting rid of stress is good and necessary when we want to live happily. But when I mean it in another way using 'way', I get it mixed up.

> 1. Getting rid of stress is the best way for living happily.
> 2. Getting rid of stress is the best way of living happily.
> 3. Getting rid of stress is the best way to living happily.

Which one is right? And for the sake of making sure that I understand it fully, could I ask difference?

Comment: What makes you sure that one is right and the other two are wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out [this Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the+best+way+*&year_start=1920&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3).

When using "the best way", that phrase is most often followed by an infinitive:

> The best way **to eat** pizza is by starting at the point.
>   The best way **to prepare** a roast is to cook it slowly.
>   The best way **to hit** a baseball is to practice – a lot.
>   The best way **to ruin** a first date is by talking about yourself too much.
>   The best way **to use** "the best way" is to follow it with an infinitive.

However, this is not the only way to use the phrase; "the best way" can also be followed by *of* with a gerund:

> The best way **of increasing** morale in the workplace is to care about the workers.
>   The best way **of preventing** a heart attack is to both exercise regularly and eat well.

A third pattern found in the Ngram results is to use "the best way" followed by *for* with a noun or pronoun:

> The best way **for teachers** to evaluate their students is by using oral exams.
>   The best way **for us** to solve this problem is to work together.

So, any of these will work in your case:

> The best way **to live** happily is to get rid of stress.
>   The best way **of living** happily is to get rid of stress.
>   The best way **for you** to live happily is to get rid of stress.

But there are other ways to say the same thing; for example, I can use "the best way is" (which is also listed on the Ngram):

> When it comes to living happily, **the best way is** to get rid of stress.

Answer (score 0):

> 3) Getting rid of stress is the best way **to live** happily.

would be best. You need to use the infinitive verb form though.

Using a dependent clause *to live happily* eliminates the need for using a preposition, where usage can get quite complicated.

Comment: True, but this is rather interesting: if we change "the best way" to "the key", then _to living_ seems to work better than _to live_: **Getting rid of stress is the key to living happily.**